# Find area of region bounded by four graphs

Tags: integration

I would like to calculate the surface of the intersection of the following equations: I already extracted the needed equations and drew the graph. 
I'd just need a tutorial or a small howto to get started on how to calculate the surface.
These are the equations I found.

- First Equation: $f(x) = 4$
- Second Equation: $g(x) = 1$
- Third Equation: $h(x) = -x + 4$
- Fourth Equation: $l(x) = 0.5(x)^2 +1$

The desired surface is in red.

[image: Image of bounded region]

Comment: This is a basic Calculus I problem, so how about if I answer your question with a question? How would you calculate the area between the second and third graphs? Then, how would you calculate the area between the second and *fourth* graphs? In each case, what horizontal limits (that is, what domain of x) would apply? Alternately, if none of *that* makes sense to you, then how would you compute the area under the fourth graph?

Comment: @qwerty12345: No need for first equation.You need to remove area of parabola patch from that of trapezium, which have known formulas.

Answer (score 1):

The area between two curves can be understood as follows: Let $f(x)$ be the top curve, and let $g(x)$ be the bottom curve. Then the area under $f(x)$ is $\int_a^b f(x) dx$. The area under $g(x)$ is $\int_a^b g(x) dx$. If we remove the area under $g$, then we have the area between them. This is $\int_a^b f(x) dx - \int_a^b g(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x) - g(x) dx$ by linearity of the integral.

So now what I would do is split up the region into two parts, since the 'top' function is piecewise defined. Find the intersection point between the green and yellow curves, call it maybe $c$. Then you want to integrate (green) - (blue from $0$ to $c$, and (yellow) - (blue) from $c$ to $3$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP has misinterpreted this exercise since the region bounded by the four graphs is the shaded region in the graph below. Otherwise the graph $y=4$ is completely irrelevant to the exercise.

The exercise is designed to be solved by integrating with respect to $y$ rather than with respect to $x$. Therefore equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ should be re-written as

\begin{equation}
x=-y+4
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x=\sqrt{2(y-1)}
\end{equation}

The integral will have to be split into two portions at the $y$-coordinate of the intersection. This is found by solving

\begin{equation}
-y+4=\sqrt{2(y-1)}
\end{equation}

Of the two solutions, the one lying between $y=1$ and $y=4$ is $y=5-\sqrt{7}$

So

\begin{eqnarray}
A&=&\int_1^{5-\sqrt{7}}-y+4-\sqrt{2(y-1)}\,dy+\int_{5-\sqrt{7}}^4\sqrt{2(y-1)}+y-4\,dy\\
&=&\left[-\dfrac{y^2}{2}+4y-\frac{1}{3}[2(y-1)]^{3/2}\right]_1^{5-\sqrt{7}}+\left[\frac{1}{3}[2(y-1)]^{3/2}+\dfrac{y^2}{2}-4y\right]_{5-\sqrt{7}}^4\\
&=&\frac{1}{6}(47-14\sqrt{7})+\frac{1}{6}(20+12\sqrt{6}-14\sqrt{7})\\
&=&\frac{1}{6}(67+12\sqrt{6}-28\sqrt{7})\\
&\approx&2.0589+1.6600=3.7189
\end{eqnarray}
[image: Plane region bounded by four graphs]